# How can i do so that in my div just fits for three child divs?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Im doing a Posts component with react js where i have many Post components inside it.

Posts.js

```
const Posts = () => {
  return (
    <div className="postsContainer">
        <Post/>
        <Post/>
        <Post/>
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default Posts;
```

Posts.css:

```
.postsContainer{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-direction:row;
    padding:100px;
}
```

Post.js:

```
const Post = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <div className="postContainer">
            <div className="userData">
                <img/>
                <p>Mateo Ghidini</p>
            </div>
            <div className="userPost">
                <img/>
            </div>
            <div className="actions">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Post
```

Post.css:

```
.postContainer{
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin:20px;
}

.userData{
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
}

.userPost{
    height:180px;
}

.actions{
    border-top:2px solid black;
    height:30px;
}
```

What is the css property so that if i enter more than three post components inside my posts components, the 4th 5th and 6th post are positioned in a row below and not continue positioning them one beside another.

So basically i want to render my post components in row of threes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property that you're most likely looking for is `flex-wrap` with the value set as `wrap`. It will ensure that in the case of overflowing the contents will be moved to the next row according to the value of the `flex-direction` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can try rendering it as css grid element

Add those to .postContainer

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
```

You can read more about css grid here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/